# Create new Object from a complex array of objects using Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, arraylist, key-value

I have an array of objects and I want to push only the values of each object inside the array to a new object as a key value pair using Javascript.

eg:

```
const prices = [
  { ticker: 'msft', price: 14.3 },
  { ticker: 'msft', price: 10.2 },
  { ticker: 'ibm', price: 9.2 },
  { ticker: 'amzn', price: 10.2 },
];
```

Output should be as below:

```
{
"msft":[10.2,14.3],
"ibm":[9.2],
"amzn":[10.2]
}
```

Comment: Why does 10.2 come before 14.3?

Comment: What have you attempted to achieve this result? Where is that going wrong?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```
const output = prices.reduce((result, object) => {
    const key = object.ticker;
    result[key] = result[key] || [];
    result[key].push(object.price);
    return result;
}, {})
```